# dynamic image cropping in react-native using React-Native-perspective-image-cropper

Tags: react-native, react-native-image, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to make dynamic image cropper. I came across [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-perspective-image-cropper) package which seems to be working absolutely as I want.

I am trying to add this in my application. I followed the steps as specified in document

1. install react-Native-perspective-image-cropper and react-native-svg and link them
2. Download opencv framework and add that in ios project

but I keep getting the error

> "opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found"

Anyone came across same kind of error and can help?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the following to your settings.gradle:

```
include ':openCVLibrary310'
project(':openCVLibrary310').projectDir = 
  new File(rootProject.projectDir,
         '../node_modules/react-native-perspective-image-cropper/android/openCVLibrary310')
```

See instructions [here](https://github.com/Michaelvilleneuve/react-native-perspective-image-cropper)